# C Passing 2d array in function gives me segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, function, malloc

I'm a beginner programmer and I am currently learning C. What I'm trying to do is read the dimensions of an array from the user, create the array using malloc and then pass the created array inside a function, the function should find the minimum number of every row in the array and place it in an other array which it will also return back to the main program. However as soon as the array is passed into the function and I try to use it I'm getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error. I know in which line the error is but I cannot locate the mistake I have made. I would really appreciate it if you guys helped me out a little bit. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *pinfun(int **pin,int sizex,int sizey);

void main(void){
    int x,y,i,j;
    int **dipin;
    int *newpin;
    printf("Parakalw eisagetai tis diastaseis x,y tou pinaka:");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    dipin =(int**) malloc(x*sizeof(int*));
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
                *(dipin+i)=(int*) malloc(y*sizeof(int));
        }
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
                for(j=0;j<y;j++){
                        printf("Parakalw eisagetai tin (%d,%d) timi tou pinaka:",i,j);
                        scanf("%d",((dipin+i)+j));
                }
        }
    newpin= pinfun(dipin,x,y);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("H elaxisti timi tis %dis grammis einai: %d",i,*pinfun);
    }
}

int *pinfun(int **pin,int sizex,int sizey){
    int i,j,min;
        int* retpin=malloc(sizeof(int)*sizex);
        for(i=0;i<sizex;i++){
                min=**pin;
                for(j=0;j<sizey;i++){
                        if(*(*(pin+i)+j) < min){
                            min =*(*(pin+i)+j);
                        }
                }
        *(retpin + i) = min;
        }
    return retpin;
}
```

The code has been been fixed. The mistake was in the scanf("%d",((dipin+i)+j)); line . By switching it to scanf("%d", (*(dipin+i)+j)) it worked like a charm. Thank you for your time.

Comment: First, learn to use [] operator, then post only a minimal example.

Comment: @2501 how can I use the [] operator if I don't know the dimensions? I'm sorry if the question sounds stupid, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: `*(*(pin+i)+j)` is the same as `pin[i][j]`

Comment: the scanf looks suspicious `((dipin+i)+j)` is a double pointer. but anyway, I would suggest using a debugger. (gdb?)

Comment: @ 2501 Yes, I realize this but I thought it wouldn't work that way because the dimensions aren't predefined. Anyway, still the reason I did it this way is because I am currently learning pointers and I want to learn how they work better.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I used the gdb and showed an error in the line min=**pin; . I have also used a min=pin[0][0] but it still didn't work.

Comment: Thank you all. It appears the mistake that was causing the problem was in the " scanf("%d",((dipin+i)+j)); " line. The code is now fixed. The reason I used pointers was so I could understand the whole concept of them better. I know [] is easier to read and understand. Again thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ghastflare ,If you got a solution,then post an answer and accept your own answer

Comment: @CoolGuy I posted the answer but it won't let me accept my own answer for two days. I will accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has been been fixed. The mistake was in:

```
scanf("%d",((dipin+i)+j));
```

By switching it to:

```
scanf("%d", (*(dipin+i)+j))
```

it worked like a charm. Thank you for your time.

Of course there were also a few other typos that were mentioned but that was what was causing the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(j=0;j<sizey;i++)
```

I haven't gone through your whole code but this looks suspicious

it shoule be

```
for(j=0;j<sizey;j++)
```

It would be good to make your code readble like.

using

```
pin[i] = *(p+i);

pin[i][j] = *(*(pin+i)+j);
```

Fix your printf() also as suggested by Cool Guy.

```
printf("H elaxisti timi tis %dis grammis einai: %d",i,newpin[i]);
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right this was a mistake, I fixed it but it still gives me the segmentation fault error .. :/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(j=0;j<sizey;i++)
```

To

```
for(j=0;j<sizey;j++)
```

And

```
printf("H elaxisti timi tis %dis grammis einai: %d",i,*pinfun);
```

To

```
printf("H elaxisti timi tis %dis grammis einai: %d",i,*(newpin+i));
```

Or

```
printf("H elaxisti timi tis %dis grammis einai: %d",i,newpin[i]);
```

to make it easier to understand

Comment: Yeap, these are all mistaked I have already fixed but the error remains... :/